# Favorite Linux Variety and why?

Tags: linux, operating-systems

Right now I have Fedora dual booted with Windows 7. The reasoning behind that is just because windows was the first OS I ever used and has some essential software, and Fedora is the first linux distribution I tried, but I would like to hear the argument for other distros, as I may be looking to switch.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: community wiki...good question! +1

Comment: do we really need *another* subjective Linux question?  [Why switch to Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/8467/why-switch-to-linux) .. [Why did you start with Linux? And why did you continue using it?](http://superuser.com/questions/9721/why-did-you-start-with-linux-and-why-did-you-continue-using-it) .. [Is there any practical reason to dual-boot Linux alongside Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/47597/is-there-any-practical-reason-to-dual-boot-linux-alongside-windows)

Comment: Well every linux distro has its own perks, it can take quite a bit of research to find that, I was wondering what people found out... the Linux from Scratch thing sounds pretty cool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Linux Install Should You Start With](http://superuser.com/questions/22570/which-linux-install-should-you-start-with)

Comment: Subjective/Argumentative.

Answer (score 6):

[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com).  This is currently the most popular distribution of linux and as such comes with many advantages.  There is much more available help for this distribution for those new to linux than I've seen in with other distribution's support.  Also, it is more user friendly (read: more gui) than most distros (though I use the command line for everything, which works just as well).  When I encounter a problem it is usually a simple google search away from an answer.  I don't just use it because it is easy (I used gentoo before this) or the most popular (I'd use windows if I wanted something popular), but because of the many other advantages from using such a highly used distro of quick support and good stability.

Comment: Enphasis on the available help. The fact that it's "popular" **really** helps when troubleshooting. And you will troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3):

[Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) is a good way to really get to know Linux.

Comment: not bad!  except it will scare novices pretty quickly...

Comment: +1 I recommend any GNU/Linux user to at least build one LFS distro to fully understand the internals. It helps them understand things and also gives them a sense of oh, so thats how it works!

Comment: That actually sounds cool. +1 just for making me aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 5.0
One of the most stable thing on Earth.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few months looking at the various distributions available, I literally went through the top 10 at Distrowatch and a few more besides. In the end it came down to two, Fedora and OpenSUSE.

for me, the ultimate choice is [openSUSE](http://distrowatch.com/suse). It's the distribution that gave me the least trouble, provided the best support, through their excellent forums and it's the one I feel most comfortable using.

Answer (score 0):

[ArchLinux](http://www.archlinux.org) is my OS of choice at the moment, 'cause it comes with just the essential, then is up to the user.